# Why isn't this simple code working, for Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
x = raw_input("Write a number")
if x.isalpha():
    print "Invalid!"
elif x%2==0:
    print "The number you have written is EVEN"
elif x%2!=0:
    print "The number you have written is ODD"
else:
    print "Invalid!"
```

It is supposed to check if the number is odd or even and print it out. My if statement checks if the raw_input was an alphabet because that won't work. And my elif statements check for odd or even.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value of `raw_input` is always a string. You'll need to convert it to an integer if you want to use the `%` operator on it:

```
x = raw_input("Write a number")
if x.isalpha():
    print "Invalid!"
x = int(x)
```

Instead of `x.isalpha()` you can use [exception handling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) instead:

```
try:
    x = int(raw_input("Write a number"))
except ValueError:
    print 'Invalid!'
else:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print "The number you have written is EVEN"
    else:
        print "The number you have written is ODD"
```

because `int()` will raise `ValueError` if the input is not a valid integer.

Comment: It looks like OP has just started learning Python. He shouldn't have learned about `try`, `execpt`, `finally` and others at this stage. I am saying this because I am pretty new too... And using `raw_input` is one of the building blocks in most of the books/tutorials... :)

Comment: @Aditya: that's why I am *suggesting* exception handling, and linked that to the tutorial section on that technique. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `raw_input` is a string, but you need a number to do the parity test.
You can check whether it's an alpha string, and if not, convert it to an int.
For example:

```
xs = raw_input("Write a number")
if xs.isalpha():
    print "Invalid!"
else:
    xn = int(xs)
    if xn % 2 == 0:
        print "The number you have written is EVEN"
    elif xn % 2 != 0:
        print "The number you have written is ODD"
    else:
        print "The universe is about to end."
```